# Simultaneous tangent line(s) to $y = \frac{1}{2}x^2$ and $g = \ln x$

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

**Question:**

Show that there is at least one straight line in the xy-plane that is simultaneously a tangent to the curve:

$$y = \frac{1}{2}x^2$$

and the curve:

$$g = \ln x,x \geq 0$$

How many such lines exist? Note that the equations of those tangents need not be determined.

The solution should use some form of calculus.

**Attempted solution:**

First, I use Wolfram Alpha to draw a plot just to get a very general idea of how the curves look. Of course, this is only a tiny part of the graph and the solutions could very well be outside the image.

### [image]

From the question, I conclude that the two functions need not touch each other in places where the tangent lines are. This is because a given tangent line could be a tangent to the first curve at one place and a tangent to the second curve at another.

At any rate, a simultaneous tangent requires identical derivatives for the two functions.

$$y = \frac{1}{2}x^2, x \in \mathbb{R}$$

$$y' = x, x \in \mathbb{R}$$

$$g = \ln x,x \geq 0$$

$$g' = \frac{1}{x}, x \neq 0$$

Setting them equal to each other:

$$y' = g' \Rightarrow x = \frac{1}{x} \Rightarrow x^2 = 1 $$

This produces the two solutions:

$$x_1 = 1$$
$$x_2 = -1$$

I am not sure how to move on from here. Intuitively, I would perhaps see if a proposed tangent line from each of the two equations had the same y intercept, but not sure how to do that without determining the formula for the tangent (something the question says is not needed).

The expected answer is: "There are two such lines" and nothing else.

Surely, it cannot be as simple as taking the derivative, putting them equal to each other getting two x values here?

How can I wrap this up?

Comment: When you set the derivatives equal to each other, you are finding the $x$ values at which both functions have the same gradient. This is not a requirement for a line to be simultaneously tangent to both. Like you said, a tangent could be touching the curves at different $x$ values.

Comment: We have two points on two curves: $y_1 = x_1^2/2, \, y_2 = \ln x_2$. The slopes of the curves at those points are the same: $x_1 = 1/x_2 = k$. We want one common tangent, not two parallel tangent lines: $(y_2 - y_1)/(x_2 - x_1) = k$. Now express everything in terms of $x_1$ to get $x_1^2 - 2 - 2 \ln x_1 = 0$. This function has exactly one extremum point, where it's negative, and goes to $\infty$ when $x_1$ goes to $0$ or to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to my comment to understand why your solution is incorrect.

We have two functions, $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2\implies f'(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\ln x\implies g'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Let the $x$-value of the point of tangency on $f(x)$ be $a$ and that of $g(x)$ be $b$.

Let us determine the general equation of a tangent for $f(x)$, then search for specific lines which only touch $g(x)$ once.

\begin{align}
y-y_1&=\dfrac{dy}{dx}(x-x_1)\\
y&=a(x-a)+\frac{1}{2}a^2 \tag{Using the point $(a,f(a)$}\\
\end{align}

Now, we solve for when this tangent intersects a point, $(b,g(b))$ on $g(x)$. Note that this will include solutions where the tangent touches $g(x)$ at more than one point.

\begin{align}
y&=a(x-a)+\frac{1}{2}a^2\\
\ln b&=a(b-a)+\frac{1}{2}a^2\\
\ln b&=ab-a^2+\frac{1}{2}a^2 \\
\ln b&=ab-\frac{1}{2}a^2\tag{1}\\
\end{align}

---

We must do the same for $g(x)$. We need to find the general equation for the tangent of $g(x)$ and find when they intersect $f(x)$. If you follow the above process, then you should end up with:

\begin{align}
y-y_1&=\dfrac{dy}{dx}(x-x_1)\\
y&=\frac{1}{b}(x-b)+\ln b \tag{Using the point $(b,\ln b$)}\\
\frac{1}{2}a^2&=\frac{1}{b}(a-b)+\ln b \\
\frac{1}{2}a^2 &=\frac{a}{b}-1+\ln b \tag{2}\\
\end{align}

Solving $(1)$ and $(2)$ simultaneously for $a$ and $b$ gives two solutions: $a=0.3982,b=2.511$ and $a=1.774,b=0.5638$, given to four significant figures. Therefore the equations of the tangents are:

$$y=0.3982(x-0.3982)+0.0793$$
and

### $$y=1.774(x-1.774)+0.1573$$

Here is a screenshot of Desmos to show the solution.[image]
[image: solution]

Comment: It is a very nice solution. Your answer is in the spirit of the question since you were able to find that there were two such tangents before calculating the precise equations of those tangents (as this only happens in the absolute final step above the graph)?